# Running three programs in the commandline, or script for recording CPU utilization while program is running

Tags: linux, bash, perl, scripting, cpu-usage

I'm trying to run 3 programs in the commandline like this:

```
program1; program2; program3
```

I want program1 to run while program2 is running.  Once program2 naturally terminates, I want program3 to explicitly terminate program1.

The purpose of this is so I can record the CPU utilization while the program is running for benchmarking purposes.

Here is an idea of what I want:

```
mpstat 1 & > CPUutil.txt ; ./a.out | tee p.txt ; perl -e '//code to kill program1'
```

If you can think of a solution that can be done entirely in a Perl script using system()/fork() instead of using only the commandline that would be just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to put `program1` into the background with `&`:

```
program1&; program2; kill $!
```

then it will run along with `program2`. `kill $!` (`$!` being the pid of most recently backgrounded process -- i.e. `program1`) will start after `program2` terminates.  If `program1` is still running, `kill $!` will terminte it.

Comment: `$!` is the pid of the most recently backgrounded process and can be used as `kill $!` for the "program3" slot of this set of commands.

Comment: Thanks it works.  Except when I try to redirect the output of program1 to a file I get a bash syntax error saying unexpected token near ";".  I got rid of the first ";" and it works without syntax errors.  Basically: "program1 & program2; kill $!"

Comment: Indeed, `&` and `;` occupy the same syntactic slot so using both isn't necessary (and as you discovered) is an error.